# Max. Entropy = Min. Energy?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy, soft-question

If a closed system has a submaximum entropy, then we can assume that in theory we can extract energy and thus the system goes to the maximum entropy state and no free energy is available. On the other hand, every physical system tends to be in a minimum energy state in the sense of internal energy.

Therefore, can we say that *the principle of maximum entropy* equals *the principle of minimum energy*?

Comment: "(sub)Maximum entropy" does not mean anything unless you state which variables are being held constant and which are varied here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I once interrupted a visiting professor in a seminar and pointed out that same thing. He got very angry.

Comment: I'm afraid that does little to make your question clearer, though - unless you specify it, it is not really clear what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max entropy = min energy **if and only if** one adds the right information about the physical conditions.

What can be proved for every thermodynamic system is that the condition of **maximum entropy at fixed internal energy**, and at fixed  remaining extensive variables (e.g. volume and number of particles, for a typical fluid system), is equivalent to the condition that **internal energy is minimum at fixed entropy** (and at fixed  remaining extensive variables).

Probably the proof makes easier to understand this duality. It can be found in every good thermodynamics textbook like Callen's *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistic*. I'll summarize it below.

First of all, it should be clear that maximum or minimum should be intended as conditions with respect to one or more variables expressing the internal constraints on the system. Let $X$ indicate a single constraint variable.

If entropy is maximum with respect to $X$, it is an extremum and the condition
$$
\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{X}} \right|_U = 0
$$
holds. But a well known identity of partial derivatives implies that $U$ must be extremum wrt $X$ at fixed $S$:
$$
Q=\left.\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S = -\frac{\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{X}}\right|_U}{\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{U}}\right|_X}=0,~~~~~~[1]
$$
since $\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{U}}\right|_X=\frac{1}{T}$ can never be zero.

In order to show that $U$ is a minimum at fixed $S$, if $S$ is a maximum at fixed $U$, we need to derive an intermediate result.
We have

$$
\left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S = \left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_U
$$
when $\left.\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S=0$. This is a consequence of the identity  $\left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S =
\left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{U}}\right|_X \left.\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S  + \left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_U $.

Therefore,
$$
\left.\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{X}^2}\right|_S = \left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_S = \left.\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{X}}\right|_U.
$$
We need to evaluate the partial derivative wrt $X$, at constant $U$ of the last ratio in equation [$1$]. The term with the derivative of the denominator vanishes because it is multiplied by $\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{X}} \right|_U $ which is zero (extemum condition). Thus, we remin with
$$
\left.\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{X}^2}\right|_S =
-\frac{\left.\frac{\partial^2{S}}{\partial{X}^2}\right|_U}{\left.\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{U}}\right|_X}= -T\left.\frac{\partial^2{S}}{\partial{X}^2}\right|_U,
$$
which is positive if the extremum of $S$ is a maximum.

I would add that a similar max/min duality holds for the corresponding legendre transforms of energy/entropy. For example (although almost trivial), the  principle of minimum Helmholtz free energy would correspond to the maximum of the Legendre transform of entropy with respect to the energy, $\tilde S(1/T,V,N) = S -\frac{U}{T}$.

Comment: Thanks, Giorgio.

Comment: Before I asked a question to this effect, I came across your answer here. I am currently reading Callen and that is what brought me here. I cannot for the life of me understand how to make sense of the minimum energy principle, and I think that much of my confusion lies in *not understanding what constant entropy means*. When Callen introduces the entropy maximum postulate, it appears to apply if and only if the composite system under investigation is isolated. It then makes sense to speak of constant energy. In contrast, I can't make sense of thinking of $S$ as an independent variable in...

Comment: ... an isolated system. You write "What can be proved for every thermodynamic system is that the condition of maximum entropy at fixed internal energy, and at fixed remaining extensive variables (e.g. volume and number of particles, for a typical fluid system), is equivalent to the condition that internal energy is minimum at fixed entropy (and at fixed remaining extensive variables)." But what does "at fixed entropy" even mean?

Comment: @EE18 From the formal point of view, there is nothing special to introduce a process where entropy is constant. From the physical point of view, it may be difficult to obtain experimentally. However, this is a practical issue, not a conceptual one. In a way., even the isolated system condition is quite hard to obtain in real systems. The value of both max-entropy and min-energy principles is in the fact that all the Legendre transforms of entropy and energy inherit them.  ...

Comment: @EE18 .. In this way, an experimentally challenging condition of constant entropy can be translated into a much simpler condition of constant temperature.

Comment: I guess I am willing to accept that Min Energy is valid for systems such that entropy is constant, but Callen seems to go a step further in Chap 5.1: he suggests that any system which can be treated by Max Ent can also be treated by Min Energy, and that we arrive at the same conclusion. I just can’t seem to square this with the fact that Max Ent only applies to isolated systems, and speaking about “constant entropy” for an isolated system seems to make zero sense. Hopefully I am making sense! Thank you as always for your help.

Comment: @EE18 The constant entropy constraint is not in addition to constant energy (isolated system). Either a system is isolated (E=const), or it is isoentropic (S-const). The two conditions do not hold at the same time.

Comment: I agree with you! But my question is then how it makes sense to claim that the two principles are equivalent when they have different domains of applicability?

Comment: @EE18 They are equivalent in the sense that each of them is enough, in addition to the other postulates, to obtain a formulation of Thermodynamics equivalent to the classical one.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to think about this more and perhaps ask a question, as I am not sure I can fully convince myself that the other postulates present the resolution to my dilemma here. Of course, that is a failure of my understanding. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Also (and this is unrelated to our earlier discussion), to claim that we have a $U$ maximum as far as I know it is not sufficient just to demonstrate that the "unmixed" partial derivatives are positive. Don't we need all mixed derivatives positive too (I'm not sure if that's equivalent to the positivity of the Hessian)?

Comment: @EE18 Maximum entropy and minimum energy, in combination with the extensiveness, are enough to prove the concavity of entropy or convexity of energy. From there, the conditions on the second derivative is a math exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A closed system will stay at the same energy, while its entropy will as you said rise to its maximum. Maximum entropy is therefore minimal free energy, but total energy won't be affected.

Comment: OK. So if the system can interact with the enviroment, then it will dissipate the free internal energy to obtain the minimum energy state?

Comment: @Hulkster Well, this is true even for non-thermodynamical systems, I guess.

Comment: @Hulkster, the entropy state of your system says something about how that system's energy is distributed.  If the energy is uniformly distributed, even for a high energy system, no energy is available for work.  In effect, a heat engine needs a temperature DIFFERENCE (non-uniformly distributed energy) in order to do work.

Comment: @DavidWhite Couldn't agree more.